# Ddos attack getting through iptables

Tags: iptables, ddos, rules

I have been using my own self-made "iptables rules" for blocking all the major type of DDOS attacks on game-servers because these attacks were application/game-server specific instead of the general DDOS attacks. It took me almost 3 years to study those attacks and respond with these rules. Up til now, I was using a rate-limit on iptables that would automatically DROP the IP if it made 250 hitcounts/sec as the client rate is much lower than this (maximum it goes is like 500kb/s). This is because attackers would generally send a large number of hit-counts with packets of the length 15:30 as this is the general packet-length where the game-server responds well. This worked really well until someone attacked with something different today to get through this rule.

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 16000:29000 -m recent --set 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 16000:29000 -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 250 -j DROP
```

Recently, I observed attacks that were easily making 1-3mb/sec of input, as seen through "iftop" to my servers and the above rules weren't blocking them because my game-server was responding with "....disconnect" packets to all the incoming connections. This happens when game-server doesn't recognize the input string or length of the packet. This was the content of the packet:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6000381/

Now as you might as well see that the packet had a huge length. According to Wireshark where I grabbed the packet, the length of the packet was 700 and data size/length was about 5000 bytes. **And I've seen this before that if you have a higher data-length/size of the packet, you can still have a higher rate even with a fewer hitcounts**. So this explains maybe why it had an input of around 3mb/s and it didn't get blocked through the hitcounts, because it never had hitcounts greater than 250..

**Now I need something that would more be bandwidth specific than the number of packets/second. I require an iptables rule that would automatically block an input>1mb/s and it may use the length of the packet if needed.** The general data-size/length of a fair game-server client would usually have packet lengths and data-size of less than 500 bytes but it might go higher in some cases but will never take more than 500kb/s of bandwidth.

The question is different than the rest of previously answered questions because it's firstly application specific. Secondly, I am asking an iptables solution that would deny any input >1mb/s?

**Update:**

I did some theoretical working to explain why a 3 Mb/s input bandwidth is not more than 250 hitcounts/second and here  is the working:

3 Mb = 3x1024x1024 = 3,145,728 bits/sec = 393,216 Bytes/sec

Hence,

If a packet had the size of 5000 bytes so the maximum number of packets per second should be:

393216/5000 = 78.6 Packets/second

And this means that if the iptables rules had to work, the packet should have been smaller than 393216/250 = **1516 bytes**.

Comment: Do you have a particular question to ask?

Comment: I need a better generalization that should be bandwidth specific like denying an input of greater than 2mb/s?

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how iptables works.  Once the traffic reaches the box which will be doing the blocking and gets processed in iptables, it has already consumed downstream bandwidth.  The canonical question explains what you can do in this scenario.

Comment: Well I do have an understanding of that. But as I mentioned, if my server outputs as a response to input then it takes double the amount of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at fail2ban? It may help you react to incoming attacks by dropping the source IPs at the firewall.

Comment: I have but I don't want IPs to accumulate into my firewall configuration so it should be more dynamic.

Comment: Why not? It's going to be much more efficient and effective if your firewall can drop any traffic from an abusive source.

Comment: Yes but you do know it would be just resource consuming rather than being something that would dynamically function at the same time rather than something that would actually monitor it at regular intervals. When someone attacks, the damage is already done with the lag I get even though IP is banned later and I cannot afford any kind of lag.

Comment: @AsadMoeen fail2ban will automatically remove the IPs from iptables after whatever time limit you specify. They do not remain in the firewall rule set indefinitely.